# Testing a setting of a parameter by a custom Solr search component

Tags: java, unit-testing, solr, lucene

I'm writing a Solr search component that all it does is setting some input parameters in its `prepare` method:

```
@Override public void prepare(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {
   ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams(rb.req.getParams());
   String paramValue = calculateParamValue();
   params.set("paramName", paramValue);
   rb.req.setParams(params);
}
```

The component sets the values of a few parameters (as shown in the simplified code sample). The components that come later in the handler's component chain use those values. I would like to separate the testing of my component and test it independently of the components that follow it in the chain. The problem is that the component doesn't add entries to Solr's response. All it does is setting parameters which are only visible to other Solr components. Unfortunately, [Solr's testing framework](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-test-framework/org/apache/solr/SolrTestCaseJ4.SVal.html) doesn't seem to let me make assertions on the parameters, just on the returned response.

Currently I'm testing the component with a dummy search component that does the tests as part of its processing. I don't like the solution because it doesn't allow me to separate test code from source code.

Is there a better way to test the component?